# How to create a dhcpd.conf file

Tags: wireless-networking, dhcp, wireless-access-point, dhcp-server

I have followed the tutorial on this [page](http://nims11.wordpress.com/2012/04/27/hostapd-the-linux-way-to-create-virtual-wifi-access-point) to create an access point on an Arch Linux install. It seems that went mostly ok apart from an error from DHCPD server:

```
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Server 4.3.0
Copyright 2004-2014 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
Wrote 0 leases to leases file.

No subnet declaration for wlan0 (no IPv4 addresses).
** Ignoring requests on wlan0.  If this is not what
   you want, please write a subnet declaration
   in your dhcpd.conf file for the network segment
   to which interface wlan0 is attached. **


Not configured to listen on any interfaces!

If you think you have received this message due to a bug rather
than a configuration issue please read the section on submitting
bugs on either our web page at www.isc.org or in the README file
before submitting a bug.  These pages explain the proper
process and the information we find helpful for debugging..

exiting.
```

Since then I have tried different conf file but no success so far. The documentation I've found so far is not exactly clear so I was wondering if anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance

Here's my dhcpd.conf file:

```
ddns-update-style none;
ignore client-updates;
authoritative;
option local-wpad code 252 = text;

subnet
10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
# --- default gateway
option routers
10.0.0.1;
# # --- Netmask
option subnet-mask
255.255.255.0;
# # --- Broadcast Address
option broadcast-address
10.0.0.255;
# # --- Domain name servers, tells the clients which DNS servers to use.
option domain-name-servers
10.0.0.1, 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
option time-offset
0;
range 10.0.0.3 10.0.0.13;
default-lease-time 1209600;
max-lease-time 1814400;
}
```

**EDIT: Here's the output of ifconfig wlan0:**

```
wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
        ether 08:bd:43:88:f2:6d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1771  bytes 352261 (344.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 33  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1436  bytes 368189 (359.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: Does your `wlan0` interface have an IP address in the range of `10.0.0.0/24`? DHCPD relies on that to determine which interfaces it should run on.

Comment: Please include the output of `ifconfig wlan0`.

Comment: I've added the output of ifconfig wlan0 in my question.